# Meego : Display locking command in terminal

Tags: qt, locking, meego

What is the command to lock the display in MeeGo OS ? I suppose it should be something based on Qt, right ? 
Particularly I would like to know the application which is being executed when user presses CTRL+ALT+L, this locks the screen and asks user to enter password in order to unlock the display.

Regards,
deimus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna answer to my own question, MeeGo use's the modified version of gnome-sreensaver project.